# commands of the music bot discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

When I try to run the `leave` and `play` command I get this error.
I've been looking for some questions for a long time but I haven't found this error anywhere how can I fix it?

**WARNING! All codes and errors have been updated on 17/11/2020 03.24 CET. If you want to check what was written before go to the edit**

Join and Leave Code:

```py
@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    v_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    print(v_channel)
    if v_channel:
        await v_channel.connect()

@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    player = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    print(player)
    if player is not None:
        await player.disconnect()
```

I put `print ()` to see what was coming out of me. Join works (in fact it finds the channel and enters) when I leave it gives me the variable but first it gives me an error. Then there is a Timeout error which automatically makes the bot exit the call but it is not important.

```
Chiamate Generali 1 #print(v_channel)
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-16' coro=<VoiceClient._create_socket() done, defined at C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py:172> exception=gaierror(11001, 'getaddrinfo failed')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 191, in _create_socket
    self.endpoint_ip = socket.gethostbyname(self.endpoint)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
<discord.voice_client.VoiceClient object at 0x05BE5658> #print(player)
Ignoring exception in command join:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/PC GIUSEPPE/PycharmProjects/LMIIBot Development/LMIIBot Development.py", line 41, in join
    await v_channel.connect()
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1080, in connect
    await voice.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 218, in connect
    await self.start_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 154, in start_handshake
    await asyncio.wait_for(self._handshake_complete.wait(), timeout=self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 490, in wait_for
    raise exceptions.TimeoutError()
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TimeoutError:
```

code on_voice_state_update:

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, prev, cur):
    print(member)
    print(prev)
    print(cur)
    if prev.channel is not None and client.user in prev.channel.members and len([m for m in prev.channel.members if not m.bot]) == 0:
        channel = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, channel=prev.channel)
        print(channel)
        await channel.disconnect()
```

I did the same thing with the commands above. Here are the errors:

```
LMII Bot Development#9553 #print(member)
<VoiceState self_mute=False self_deaf=False self_stream=False channel=None> #print(prev)
<VoiceState self_mute=False self_deaf=False self_stream=False channel=<VoiceChannel id=638017907791626250 name='Chiamate Generali 1' position=14 bitrate=128000 user_limit=0 category_id=637626960599842825>> #print(cur)
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-15' coro=<VoiceClient._create_socket() done, defined at C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py:172> exception=gaierror(11001, 'getaddrinfo failed')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 191, in _create_socket
    self.endpoint_ip = socket.gethostbyname(self.endpoint)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
Peppe Grasso#9737 #print(member)
<VoiceState self_mute=False self_deaf=False self_stream=False channel=<VoiceChannel id=638017907791626250 name='Chiamate Generali 1' position=14 bitrate=128000 user_limit=0 category_id=637626960599842825>> #print(prev)
<VoiceState self_mute=False self_deaf=False self_stream=False channel=None> print(cur)
<discord.voice_client.VoiceClient object at 0x05454670> print(channel)
```

Play code:

```py
ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
}

def endSong(guild, path):
    os.remove(path)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url):
    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send('You are not connected to a voice channel') #message when you are not connected to any voice channel
        return

    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    print(channel)
    voice_client = await channel.connect()
    print(voice_client)
    guild = ctx.message.guild

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        file = ydl.extract_info(url, download=True)
        path = str(file['title']) + "-" + str(file['id'] + ".mp3")

    voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(path), after=lambda x: endSong(guild, path))
    voice_client.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice_client.source, 1)

    await ctx.send(f'**Music: **{url}') #sends info about song playing right now
```

Error:

```
ERROR: MYAKzSEKe-g: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 797, in extract_info
    ie_result = ie.extract(url)
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 532, in extract
    ie_result = self._real_extract(url)
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\youtube.py", line 1909, in _real_extract
    raise ExtractorError(
youtube_dl.utils.ExtractorError: MYAKzSEKe-g: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/PC GIUSEPPE/PycharmProjects/LMIIBot Development/LMIIBot Development.py", line 80, in play
    file = ydl.extract_info(url, download=True)
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 820, in extract_info
    self.report_error(compat_str(e), e.format_traceback())
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 625, in report_error
    self.trouble(error_message, tb)
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 595, in trouble
    raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: MYAKzSEKe-g: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: DownloadError: ERROR: MYAKzSEKe-g: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data
```

Comment: Make sure to change your token since it has been comprised

Comment: already the token, so I'm using the one I use to test commands is not the official one

Comment: Just to make sure you know, anyone can still get your token by checking your post's edit history.

Comment: I have already changed the token itself

Comment: All of your errors might be related to that your versions are all out of date. If updating discord.py causes a conflict, then perhaps your other dependencies are out of date. I am unsure where you got the versions as a reference, but I recommend updating everything. Versions of dependencies are updated because there are bugs to be fixed. If you are still having issues, I recommend putting the version number of the dependency that was related.

Comment: Also, this is why you should build one piece at a time. Either you used outdated codebase and/or decided to build it all at once, but right now, you are having multiple issues rather than having to deal with one at a time which can be related to one or another, or they could be all unrelated. But we would have a better idea if it was built one piece at a time.

Comment: In the end I updated the version and I have only problems with the play. I have searched everywhere and unfortunately there is nothing that can help me. I solved many of the problems doing the update but I only have problems with the last command ie `play`. If there is a good solution otherwise it does nothing.

Comment: @peppewarrior1 You have not told me the version of youtube-dl that you are using. Also, what is the output of `youtube-dl -v MYAKzSEKe-g`

Comment: The version is 2020.11.1.1 and the rest I don't know, I randomly picked this code as it was the only one easier to get it from.

Comment: @peppewarrior1 once again, please update it to the latest version which is `2020.11.19`. Also, you still not have shown me the command output of `youtube-dl -v MYAKzSEKe-g`

Comment: It doesn't find me this version and it tells me that the version I have is the latest (I use pycharm and search from there) and I can't find the output you tell me anywhere. Is the code I showed correct? If not, is there a solution? Otherwise I give you the 50 points for the help you have given me in most and end.

Comment: @peppewarrior1 Here is the link to the direct repository: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#installation. If your IDE cannot find the latest version of a package, that is another problem.

Comment: its path the septum in the folder where the bot is located or is it also good on the desktop?

Comment: @peppewarrior1 as long as your files can see where the dependency is installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: Just update all of your dependencies.

The member variable `channel` of `prev` is of type `None`. It is telling you the error in the traceback. Somehow, you need to ensure that `channel` of `prev` is set to a value that is not `None`, or the very least, check that.

Here is a simple check:

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, prev, cur):
    if prev.channel is not None and client.user in prev.channel.members and len([m for m in prev.channel.members if not m.bot]) == 0:
        channel = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, channel=prev.channel)
        await channel.disconnect()
```

The [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState.channel) describe why `channel` would be `None`.

The variable `player` is of type `None`. It is telling you the error in the traceback. Somehow, you need to ensure that `player` is a value that is not `None`, or the very least, check that.

```py
@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    player = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if player is not None:
        await player.disconnect()
```

The [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.voice_client) describe why `player` would be `None`.

The socket error with `leave()` is probably the same issue. It fails perhaps because there is nothing to leave.

Comment: How come it doesn't release then? If the problem is not solved it always gives me the same errors in the end, however I would like something to be released so that it works. How can I do?

Comment: @peppewarrior1 can you clarify what you mean? I would fix the None issues first. As the docs say, `None if the user is not currently in a voice channel` and `Returns the VoiceProtocol associated with this guild, if any.` Do you get any errors on `join()`? Can your bot join a channel?

Comment: my bot can enter the call but cannot exit as I get the same error

Comment: Just to confirm. In the Discord UI, you can visually see it join a channel? I am assuming you got some of the code from elsewhere rather than the current docs because discord.py has been updated. I would use `ctx.voice_client` instead `ctx.message.guild.voice_client`. Try setting `force` to `True` for the `disconnect()`. What version is your discord.py?

Comment: I use 1.3.4. I update the codes and errors so I can understand better. Sorry for this waste of time I haven't had a good time lately. Then where should I set `True`?

Comment: I would update your version to the latest version which is 1.5.1. This just seems like a bug https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/5191. Also that Discord has recently implemented Intents, so I highly recommend keeping your discord python library updated.

Comment: But wouldn't I have everything in conflict? I wouldn't want to do it all again

Comment: EDIT: I updated and now it goes but I have a problem with the play command. I updated the code if you want to take a look

Answer (score 0):

Please don't allow none values into the function

```
async def on_voice_state_update(member, prev, cur):
    if client.user in prev.channel.members and len([m for m in prev.channel.members if not m.bot]) == 0:
        channel = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, channel=prev.channel)
        if channel:
            await channel.disconnect()

@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    v_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    if v_channel:
        await v_channel.connect()

@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    player = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if player:
        await player.disconnect()
```

Comment: How come it doesn't release then? If the problem is not solved it always gives me the same errors in the end, however I would like something to be released so that it works. How can I do?